# pandas get_dummies on rows with multiple entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe like this:

| Fruits |
| --- |
| apple, banana, strawberry |
| apple |
| strawberry, apple |

I am having trouble creating dummy columns for something like this, as it may have multiple fruits in each row. This would be my desired outcome:

| apple | banana | strawberry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |

Trying the get_dummies function by itself does not work, since it will create the columns like:

| apple,banana,strawberry | apple | strawberry,apple |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: This is easy to do by hand, right?  Just go through the original row by row to figure out which columns you need, then make a second pass to create the rows.  I'm not sure why your original data should be in pandas at all.  Why not just a list of strings?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, using the technique I mentioned in my comment:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    ['apple, banana, strawberry'],
    ['apple'],
    ['strawberry, apple']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Fruits'])
print(df)

columns = set()
for row in df['Fruits'].to_list():
    columns |= set( row.split(', ') )

rows = []
for row in df['Fruits'].to_list():
    rows.append( [int(c in row) for c in columns] )

columns = list(columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                      Fruits
0  apple, banana, strawberry
1                      apple
2          strawberry, apple
   apple  banana  strawberry
0      1       1           1
1      1       0           0
2      1       0           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this

```
dummy_df = df["Fruits"].str.get_dummies(", ")
```

Output

```
  apple banana strawberry
0     1      1          1
1     1      0          0
2     1      0          1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do so with a help of a standard library to get neat and pretty code.

```
from itertools import chain

def create_dummy(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Get list of all unique fruits
    fruits_series = df["Fruits"].str.split(", ")
    unique_fruits = set(chain.from_iterable(fruits_series))

    # Create dummy DataFrame
    tdf = pd.DataFrame(0,
                       columns=list(unique_fruits),
                       index=df.index,
                       dtype=pd.UInt8Dtype)

    # Update labels
    for ind, targets in zip(df.index, fruits_series):
        tdf.loc[ind, targets] = 1

    return tdf
```

Usage:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["apple, orange, grape", 
                   "apple", 
                   "banana, strawberry"], columns=["Fruits"])
print(create_dummy(df))
```

Output:

```
       grape  strawberry  orange apple banana
 0      1           0       1     1      0
 1      0           0       0     1      0
 2      0           1       0     0      1
```

Tested on `python==3.10.8` and `pandas==1.5.2`.